# Infinite loop using regex

Tags: java, regex, cycle

What's wrong with my regex or statement in cycle? I need 8-chars combination with one digit, one letter in upper case and one in lower case minimum.
But I get a non-stop cycle.

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream getPassword() throws IOException{

    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
    Random random = new Random();
    String out = "";
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();;
    while (!out.matches("[0-9]+$") | !out.matches("[a-z]+$") | !out.matches("[A-Z]+$")) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        out = sb.toString();
    }
    stream.write(out.getBytes());
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: I had to click on this question simply because of the title.

Comment: How could a string end with a digit, a small letter and a capital letter at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Java's `matches()` must match **the whole string** to return `true`, so your loop condition will always be true (the input can't both all digits *and* all letters).

There are two ways to fix your problem:

1) Add `.*` to each end of you regexes:

```
if (!out.matches(".*[0-9].*") | !out.matches(".*[a-z].*") | !out.matches(".*[A-Z].*"))
```

2) Use one, albeit more complex, regex:

```
if (!out.matches("(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8}"))
```

The last option also checks that the length is 8.

Also note that you don't need `^` or `$` with `matches()` - they are implied by the contract.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i should read much more about using regex and forming it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- regex are not necessarily the best way to express such constraints. Going through the password a single time while counting the number of occurrences of each character type would solve this just as well.
- you're using binary `OR` (`|`) instead of logical `OR` (`||`). For booleans it will behave the same but you almost certainly did not do it on purpose.
- the dollar at the end of your regex means *end of string*. You don't really care whether the character is at the beginning, middle or end of the string, you only want it to be *somewhere*.
- `matches` attempts to match the entire string. Your code would work using `find` instead or adding `.*` on both ends of each regex.

Comment: Thank you, there are important observations for me, apart from the fact that I know about features of binary (|).